# Assign Permissions and Roles Sub domain Specific Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have  4 subdomains . I am using a shared database . How to set up permissions for all subdomains specifically . Means assign different permissions for subdomain A and B but I need that in my shared Database in Drupal . Please help

Answer (score 0):

For those four subdomains you can create 4 roles such as AdminA, AdminB, AdminC etc. and assign these role to the user of the subdomains.

Then you have to apply a condition using the base url and redirect the user with access denied error if he did not assign that role.

E.g. AdminA has the right to access subdomainA so, when he access the other domain he will saw a access denied error and logout of the site.

Hope that helps.